# including file from parent folder

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I have a setup folder, and for organization sake, I'm putting everything in folders. I noticed when I have a wxs file in sub folder and I include a wxi file that located in root folder, i get error about properties that cannot be found (since they defined in wxi file).

Is it possible to include wxi file located in root folder to a wxs file in sub folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Folder just for my includes and reference like so at the top of each wxs file:

```
<?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)Includes\Includes.wxi?>
```

Change the name of the folder to your own and the name of your wxi file and that should be you...:)

Comment: It works for me only in .wxs files that located in project root. When I do that in .wxs that located in sub folder - it does not work

Comment: I have files in different folders using that same code. The `$(sys.CURRENTDIR)` should take it back to the root folder.